# Apache Server wont change root directory

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Here is my vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot K:/phpstormproject
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory K:/phpstormproject>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here are the main lines from httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "K:/xxamp/apache"

<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "K:/phpstormproject"
```

```
<Directory "K:/phpstormproject">
  AllowOverride All
  Options None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "K:/phpstormproject">
  AllowOverride All
  Options None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is everything i have eddited so far, but whenver i start appache and go to my localhost i get the phpinfo(); from the index that is in the xampp folder.
And there all the roots are poining to the xampp directory.

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT   K:/xxamp/htdocs
REQUEST_SCHEME  https
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   K:/xxamp/htdocs
```

Which is very confusing why it doesnt take the index.php that i have in my K:/phpstormproecjt directory. Where my index just says

```
echo "test";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the URL you are using

Comment: Do you mean localhost ?